# How to retrieve a button inside a ListView which is inside a Repeater

Tags: asp.net

I want to access the button `btn3` inside a ListView. The ListView itself is in the ItemTemplate of a Repeater.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rep1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            ...
            <asp:Button ID="btn3"  runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("likes").ToString()%>'/>  
            ...
        </asp:ListView>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

When I try to access `btn3` in the `ItemDataBound` event of the Repeater, the returned value is null:

```
protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{       
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Button btn1 = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("Btn3"); // btn1 is null
    }
}
```

Comment: Case sensitive? btn3 is not the same as Btn3

Comment: Hi it is  Button btn1 =(Button)e.Item.FindControl("btn3"); I typed it wrong above. So the problem is not case sensitive.I cannot access the button ,it is showing btn1=null when debugging.

Comment: In your example you are using: `Button btn1 =(Button)e.Item.FindControl("Btn3"); `

Comment: sorry i typed that by mistake in above code.I have actually used btn3 .While debugging btn1 value is null.

Comment: What about: `Button button = (Button)sender;`
`string buttonID = button.ID;`

Comment: Inside itemdatabound i have accessed Button id by Button btn1 =(Button)e.Item.FindControl("btn3")

Comment: is the button inside the itemtemplate?

Comment: Inside item template of repeater  there is list view and inside list view item template there is button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `ItemDataBound` event handler of the ListView:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rep1">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ListView1_ItemDataBound" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
            ...
        </asp:ListView>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And retrieve the button in code-behind:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
    {
        Button btn3 = e.Item.FindControl("btn3") as Button;
        ...
    }
}
```

---

If you want to do it in the Repeater `ItemDataBound` event handler (but I am not sure if the ListView is populated at that point):

```
protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{       
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        ListView ListView1 = e.Item.FindControl("ListView1") as ListView;
        List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();

        foreach (ListViewItem lvItem in ListView1.Items)
        {
            buttons.Add(lvItem.FindControl("Btn3") as Button);
        }

        // Use the list of buttons
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi how can we access button inside repeater listview. Your answer allows to access the values inside only in listview.In my case.                                              'Button btn1 = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btn3"); // btn1 is null btn1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return likessubmit('" + msgidlbl.Text + "');"); ' Here msgidlbl is inside repeater so able to access it. I need to pass the data to Javascript  hence need msglbl value.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion? It allows to get the button in the ListView, even when the ListView is inside a Repeater. You will get the Button for each ListView item of each Repeater item.

Comment: I want to access listview inside repeater_itemdatabound as in my question. How can i access listview inside repeater itemdatabound.Since iam passing the value as webservices from repeateritemdatabound ,i don't want it to be accessed seperately as your suggestion.Any other method to access it.Thanks

Comment: Hi I need button btn3 value outside for loop .How can i get the value.

Comment: There is one button for each item of the ListView, right? So, outside of the `foreach` loop, you would get a list of buttons. Is that what you want? I modified my answer to show how you can do that.

Comment: Thanks Connors ..Worked well !